# Global variable inside of function

Tags: php

Code below prints produces error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: x in C:\wamp\www\h4.php on line 9
```

and output:

```
Variable x inside function is:
Variable x outside function is: 5
```

Code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$x = 5; // global scope

function myTest() {
    // using x inside this function will generate an error
    echo "<p>Variable x inside function is: $x</p>";
} 
myTest();

echo "<p>Variable x outside function is: $x</p>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

What gets wrong with `x` global variable inside of `myTest` function?

Comment: `$x = 5; // global scope` - false.

Comment: Best to pass it in your function. Global is often frowned upon by many coders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this:

```
function myTest() {
    global $x;
    // using x inside this function will generate an error
    echo "<p>Variable x inside function is: $x</p>";
}
```

The `global` command says to use the global value of $x rather than a private one.

Comment: Or You can just type error_reporting(0); for preventing notices and errors.

Comment: No, suppressing errors is very much not what is wanted. The OP wants the global value of `$x` inside the function.

Comment: Ok then just define it global as you said...!! (Y)

Answer (score 2):

To access global variable you need to define with 'global' keyword with in the function.After define it you can access that global variable.

```
      $x = 5; // global scope

        function myTest() {
//use global keyword to access global variable
            global $x;
            // using x inside this function will generate an error
            echo "<p>Variable x inside function is: $x</p>";
        } 
        myTest();

    echo "<p>Variable x outside function is: $x</p>";
```